# Is there a keyboard shortcut to edit comment attribute in windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, comments

Is there a keyboard shortcut to edit comment or any property of a file in windows 10. For example :- We have "F2" key for rename.

Comment: Many fields can be edited from the **Details** Pane in **Explorer**.

Comment: I know that but the process involves 3 steps for each . There should be something simpler as this is very basic requirement.

Comment: What types of files do you want to add a comment? For images there are far better tools available than the Windows Explorer that allow you to add comments as EXIF data.

Comment: I want to add comments to mp4 files

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the same comment to all of them/remove all of the comments just select all of the files, open the properties of all of them at the same time and edit the comment field in the details tab, that should work